# Powershell: json and dot including value variable access

Tags: json, powershell

I have a problem accessing json-objects of predictable structure but unknown depth in Powershell. So the json-objects contain information that can be connected by "and" and "or", but those connections can be used in several levels. As an exanple:

```
$ab=@"
{
"cond":   "one",
"and":  [
{"cond":   "two"},
{"cond":  "three"},
{"or": [{"cond": "four"},
{"cond": "five"}
]
}
]
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I need to be able to read/test something like

```
$test="and.or"
$ab.$test.cond
```

where $test is a combination of several "and"s and "or"s like *and.or.or.and* .
The problem is that I can't figure out how my idea of $ab.$test.cond is to be written in Powershell to work. In theory I could test all possible combinations to a given depth by hand, but I'd prefer not to. Does anyhow have an idea how this could work? Thanks a lot!

(Powershell Version 5)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should define a proper set of classes for your conditional engine/descriptors, either using PowerShell classes or using C# to create an assembly so you can use the types within PowerShell.

But for a quick and dirty PowerShell solution, you could do this:

```
"`$ab.$test.cond" | Invoke-Expression
# or
'$ab.{0}.cond' -f $test | Invoke-Expression
```

This has no error checking of course. Any other solution is likely going to be a separate recursive function if you want to get real checking and such, but it will be more fragile then using a well-defined set of objects.